# How Can I Set an Environment Variable Equal to a Different Environment Variable in a package.json Script?

Tags: database, environment-variables, package.json, prisma

So I want to do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "DB_URL=DB_MIGRATION_URL prisma migrate deploy"
}
```

Where before I run a command, I set an enviornment variable equal to the value of another env variable. I got it working by manually adding the value like: "DB_URL="postgres..." prisma migrate deploy" but cannot figure out how to do it dynamically.

I have seen things about cross-env or dotenv, just need pointed in right direction!

The reason I want to do something like this is on my Database, there are different values for DB_MIGRATION_URL depending on what branch we are deploying from, so hard-coding only works for either staging or production, and I want it to work from both.

Thank you.

Comment: You can utilize cross-env for this. This clearly spelt out their documentation on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Answer (score 0):

Use dotenv.

Example:

```
npm install dotenv
```

Code wise:

```
# Will load .env (which contains all the values for your different environment variables),
# from your root directory.
# There are means to provide another specific .env file....

require('dotenv').config();

#You can then use it in your code this way...

# Will print the value of your S3_BUCKENT environment variable.
# console.log(process.env.S3_BUCKET)
```

.env (in your root folder):

```
VAR1="..."
VAR2="..."
...
```

More information are available here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html